# moving onto the next page using selenium by python

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```
url_main = "https://comic.naver.com/webtoon/detail.nhn?titleId=131385&no=292"
```

This webpage has pagination for comments in the end. When I inspected the page, the buttons were compiled like below:

```
<a href="#" class="u_cbox_page" data-action="page#move" data-log="RPC.pgnum"><span class="u_cbox_num_page">3</span></a>
```

I want to click one of these buttons, so I tried

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.get(url_main)
driver.switch_to.frame('commentIframe')
view_all_comments = driver.find_element_by_xpath('''//*[@id="cbox_module"]/div/div[8]/a''')
view_all_comments.click()
page_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".u_cbox_page")
page_buttons[2].click()
```

But it returns

```
StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `.u_cbox_page` returns only one match, how can you use a subscript as `page_buttons[2]`?

Comment: If you execute the code from the top to `view_all_comments.click()`, you will find 10 matches for .u_cbox_page. It is equivalent to clicking the "전체 댓글 더보기" button in the end.

Comment: ahhh, I missed that step :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait for the first button to be clickable using `WebDriverWait` `element_to_be_clickable` and wait for the presence of the other buttons using `WebDriverWait` `visibility_of_all_elements_located` like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec

driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.get(url_main)
driver.switch_to.frame('commentIframe')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
view_all_comments = wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '''//*[@id="cbox_module"]/div/div[8]/a''')))
view_all_comments.click()
page_buttons = wait.until(ec.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".u_cbox_page")))
page_buttons[2].click()
```

Comment: It returns `TimeoutException`, even after lengthening the waiting time to 60s. Does the code work fine with your computer?

Comment: I edited the answer: `visibility_of_all_elements_located` is better than `presence_of_all_elements_located` in this case. Now it will work fine

Comment: Now it works fine, but it raises another problem: it returns `StaleElementReferenceException` again whenever I try to click another button (e.g. executing `page_buttons[3].click()` after executing `page_buttons[2].click()`) . I can solve this by re-defining page_buttons again between the codes, but I want to know why I can't click another button right away in the first place.

Comment: because the buttons changed in the DOM so you need to re-define page_buttons again or take a single button at a time